# Reading dates from Excel into a DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I'm trying to read an Excel file into a `DataTable` which contains a column that has dates. Not every row will have the date cell completed (occasionally it can be empty). Usually the format of the date in the `DataTable` is `dd.MM.yyyy` but some times, depending on the file that is being read, the format is being switched to `M/dd/yyyy`. Which will throw an error when converting to `DateTime`.

How can this be solved?

I've tried parsing the data like this:

```
string[] formats = { "M/d/yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy" };
date = DateTime.ParseExact(row["Delivery date"].ToString(), formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

which seems to work almost every time. Except it reverses the the month sometimes. (ie. `05.11.2015` will be inserted as `11.05.2015`).

Comment: What do you mean by _it reverses the the month sometimes_ exactly? Sometimes your excel has this `11.05.2015` (`MM.dd.yyyy`) kind of value? If so, just add `MM.dd.yyyy` to your `formats` array? By the way, isn't `row["Delivery date"]` returns `DateTime` _already_?

Comment: Are you saying some rows in the file format date differently? Or the whole file is formatted one way or the other?

Comment: The whole file is formatted one way or another.